# Automatic login with LightOpenID after first authentication?

Tags: openid, lightopenid

I've got a situation where I'm being required to have my app fit a list of workflows, one of which requires that if a user authenticates using OpenID, all future visits to our site will automatically log them in ONLY on the condition that they're logged in to the OpenID provider.

Here's an example:

Jane logs in to our website using Chrome and OpenID with Acme as the OpenID Provider. Jane exits Chrome and opens FireFox. She logs into Acme but NOT our website. When she visits our website, our script detects that she's logged into Acme and automatically authenticates her into her account.

We're successfully using LightOpenID for authentication, but we aren't using this automatic piece. How can we accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to send the user to our OpenID login URL instead of our homepage.